# Alias can't save forever on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, alias

I want to create my own alias to make some command more simpler.I add 
`alias ll='ls -l'` in `~/.bashrc`,like this:

```
 ANDROID_NAME=/Users/smy/Library/Android/sdk
 PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
 PATH=$ANDROID_NAME/platform-tools:$PYTHONPATH:$PATH

 export ANDROID_HOME
 export PYTHONPATH
 export PATH

 #alias 
 alias ll='ls -l'
```

when I first add this alias to this file,I execute `source` command,like this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then in this command window,it can works,but when I create a new command window,it can't recognize the `ll` alias,that is when I execute `ll`,such error exists:

```
-bash: ll: command not found
```

when I type `source ~/.bashrc`,it will work.

So my question is:
**why the alias can't be recognized whenever I type it,why I must execute `source` command to make it work when new command window opened,and how I can resolve this.** I'm working on mac,Anyone can teach me about this,thanks!

Comment: Enter `echo $SHELL` and see whether the output really is `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @DarkDust,yes,I test it,its' really `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` for login shells instead of `~/.bashrc`. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files):

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

and:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

When opening a new terminal window/tab, the shell should be opened as a *login* shell.

Comment: thanks for your answer,it works.And another question is why when I execute `source ~/.bashrc`,it will works.thanks very much!

Comment: See the [documentation for `.` (`source` is a synonym for `.`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins). With that command you inject the commands of the script into your current shell's context.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the alias you need into ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash
Go to Terminal -> Preferences -> Generals -> Shell opens with -> Command (complete path) -> /bin/bash

Comment: I inserted the aliases I needed on the ~/.bash_profile and the the explained procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Only one things worked for me, and I haven't seen it mentioned yet.

In addition to

1. making sure that my `.bash_profile` file included the relevant alias/aliases
2. ensuring in the Terminal > Preferences > General window that the `Shell opens with` option selected is `/bin/bash`

I needed to ensure that the bash profile is loaded using `bash -l` each time a new window is opened. Probably spent 30m hunting for this, so hope it helps folks who are updating to the latest versions of their MacOS (like yours truly today)!

[image]